# How to apply the "active" class in the links of a navigation bar using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with bootstrap and vanilla js. What I want to do is that when you click on one of the links you will be assigned the "active" class.

So far I have the following code:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".links-menu");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  link.onclick = function() {
    var prev = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    if (prev && prev[0]) {
      prev[0].classList.remove("active");
    }
    this.classList.add("active");
  };
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  ul li a {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    color: #611ac5;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #611ac5;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  }
}

.active {
  color: #611ac5 !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #611ac5;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-2">
  <div class="container-fluid px-2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-0 text-center">
      <li class="nav-item px-3"><a href="#" class="nav-link pb-1 px-0 links-menu">home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item px-3"><a href="#" class=" links-menu nav-link pb-1 px-0">contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item px-3"><a href="#" class=" links-menu nav-link pb-1 px-0">about</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<header class="Banner-inicio container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
    <div class="Detalles-b mx-auto text-center my-5 py-5">
      <h1 class="text-center mt-md-5 mb-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
      <p class="text-center mb-md-5 mx-3">doloremque quaerat maxime sed, quis, quod accusamus quibusdam. Quos quas repudiandae fugiat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

but when clicked and redirected to the other page, it seems that the class was not assigned.

what I want is that when I click on a link and redirect to another page, that link appears with that class "active"

I know what can be done with JQuery and it is easier, but I do not want to use this library only by a navigation bar

Comment: How are you navigating pages?

Comment: You need to use PHP or try that with cookies in JS

Comment: Ale do you have the new routes that the user ends up on?

Comment: It is a mini project and literally the pages are: /index.html,   /contact.html   ,/about.html

Comment: I think that if you add an id to the links then you can create a function to handle it as in (<a href="the web page" onclick="jsfunction(this.id)…) that should allow you to pass the link id to the function. Once at the function, you can put in your logic.

Comment: Oops! I forgot... a href="" id="myid" …/a>

Answer (score 0):

I’d put a data attribute on the h1 for each page that signifies which menu option corresponds to the current page. Then, on page load, get the h1 dataset and add the active class to the right menu item. The only downside to this is that the menu item will flicker from not active to active. Unless you store the clicked menu item on the backend and add the class during the dim render though, I don’t see a great way to avoid the flicker.